# Probability that the second throw of a fair die exceeds the first

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

A player throws an ordinary die and records the score $A$.  The player then throws the die again and again records the score, $B$. if $B>A$ then we set a score for this player.  What is the probability that a player didn't get any score?  The short answer given in the  Last Chapter of my book says $\frac{7}{12}$.

***Anyone can help me to solve this question?***

Comment: This is not clear.  the way I read it:  "the player throws a pair of dice and records the value, $A$.  the player then throws the dice again, and again records the value, $B$.  What is the probability that $B>A$?"  Is this what you intended?  If so, then, by symmetry, the answer is $\frac 12 \times (1-p_{tie})$ where $p_{tie}$ denotes the probability that $B=A$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried anything? For example enumerating the possible outcomes and counting outcomes that means the player didn't get scores and those the player did get scores?

Comment: @lulu for example in first throw the playear gets value A and in the second  throw gets value B, if B>A then he gets a score.

Comment: we want calculate that a playear gets no point, would you please edit my question? @lulu

Comment: I have edited the language, please check that I kept your meaning.  In my first comment, I wrote out a way to get the answer...all you have to do to complete it is to compute $p_{tie}$.  Can you do that?

Comment: The connection between the title and the body of the question is unclear; the body doesn't mention any points.

Comment: I should say...the version of the problem I wrote does not have the solution $\frac 7{12}$.  To get that answer, the player should only be throwing one die.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Pretty sure you meant just one die...I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @lulu this is my correction, okey now?

Comment: this version looks fine.  My comment still applies...can you compute $p_{tie}$?

Comment: No this is my misunderestand points, Thanks if you learn me @lulu

Comment: With just one die, it is is easy to enumerate all the possibilities.  There are $6$ equally probable values for $A$, and likewise for $B$.  Thus, $36$ equally likely possibilities for the pair $(A,B)$.  Write them all down and count the ties!  There are other methods, of course, but enumeration is good when it is possible.

Comment: :) its a very easy question :) thanks so much I get it. thanks very much @lulu

Comment: Just $1/6(5/6+4/6+3/6+2/6+1/6+0/6)=15/36\approx 42%$ for $B>A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straight forward, but somewhat tedious solution is to simply list the outcomes:

- First throw 1 then throw 1, no score
- First throw 1 then throw 2, score
- First throw 1 then throw 3, score

etc.

Then it's just a matter of counting scores vs no scores (every outcome is equally probable). I get $15$ outcomes that scores and $21$ that doesn't (there's $36$ in total). This gives the probability $21/36 = 7/12$.

You can also make it more compact by just considering the probabily for no-score given the first throw. If thrown a $1$ the probability for no-score is $1/6$, if thrown a $2$ the probability is $2/6$ and so on. For each first throw the probability is $1/6$ so the probability becomes:

$${1\over6}{1\over6}+
{1\over6}{2\over6}+  
{1\over6}{3\over6}+  
{1\over6}{4\over6}+  
{1\over6}{5\over6}+  
{1\over6}{6\over6} = 21/36 = 7/12
$$

Comment: We have 3 situation, first A>B, A<=B and A=B. We must count all situation that A<B. isn't it?

Comment: ? I wait for your description

Comment: @USAMath Yes, we count all situation where $A<B$, namely $1<2$, $1<3$, $1<4$, $1<5$, $1<6$, $2<3$, $2<4$, $2<5$, $2<6$, $3<4$, $3<5$, $3<6$, $4<5$, $4<6$ and $5<6$ which are $15$ cases. The other $21$ cases is where the player does not score.

Comment: thanksss. is it possible to add a short description about last formula in your answer? the formula that calculate 7/12. I read text but not very clear for me

Comment: @USAMath The second formula? Yes, for example the probability that you throw a $3$ is $1/6$, and given you've throw'n a $3$ first the probability that you don't score is $3/6$ (the second throw is $1$, $2$ or $3$) - this means that the probability that you throw a $3$ first and not score is the product of these independent events, that is ${1\over 6}{3\over 6}$. Then you sum the probabilities of not scoring for each first throw you can have - the sum because the events are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a table. The names of the rows are the outcomes of the first dice (d1). The names of the columns are the outcomes of the second dice. In total we have 36 possible outcomes. And the cells marked with $\color{red}x$ are the outcomes where the second dice has a greater outcome than the first dice.

$ \begin{array}[ht]{|p{2cm}|||p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|}  \hline \text{ d1/d2 }  & 1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6  \\ \hline \hline \hline 1 & &\color{red}x &\color{red}x &\color{red}x &\color{red}x &\color{red}x \\  \hline  2&  & &\color{red}x &\color{red}x &\color{red}x&\color{red}x  \\ \hline 3& & & &\color{red}x &\color{red}x&\color{red}x \\ \hline 4 & & &&&\color{red}x&\color{red}x  \\ \hline  5 & &&&&&\color{red}x  \\ \hline  6&&&&&&  \\ \hline \end{array}$

Count the red x´s. And the probabilty that the player **does not win** is 1 minus the probability that the player does win.

Comment: you means (1-15/36)?

Comment: @USAMath Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

The probability of a tied result on a fair die: $\mathsf P(A=B) ~=~ \tfrac 1 6$

By symmetry: $\mathsf P(A>B)~=~\mathsf P(B>A)$.

By total probability: $~\color{blue}{\mathsf P(B>A)}~$ $\color{blue}{=~ \tfrac 12(1-\mathsf P(A=B)) ~\\=~ \dfrac 5{12}}$

---

**Note:** *if* you wanted a tie or greater:  $~\mathsf P(B\geq A) ~$$=~ \mathsf P(A=B)+\mathsf P(B>A) ~\\=~ \dfrac 7 {12}$

Answer (score 0):

Since you want multifarious methods, out of $36$ possible outcomes, $A=B$ in $6$.

By symmetry, $15$ of the remaining $30$ must have $B>A$, thus $P(\;set\;score) = \frac{15}{36}$

and P(**not** set score) $= 1 - \frac{15}{36}$

Comment: 1-(15/36) is answer :)

Comment: Oh, I computed for P(set score) ! Amended.

Comment: Btw, the heading asks for P(set score)